# Reading from pipe in python is imposiible

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe, popen

Hello I have the following code in python 2.6:

```
command = "tcpflow -c -i any port 5559"
port_sniffer = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True)
while True:
    line = port_sniffer.stdout.readline()
    #do some stuff with line
```

The purpose of this code is to sniff the traffic between two processes (A and B) that communicate on port 5559.

Now let me describe the different scenarios I am having:

1) Code above is not running:
A and B are communicating and i can see it clearly using logs and the linux command `netstat -napl | grep 5559` shows that the processes are communicating on the desired port.

2) Code above is not running and I am sniffing by running `tcpflow -c -i any port 5559` directly from shell:
I can see the communication on console clearly :-).

3) Code above is running: Proccesses can't communicate. `netstat -napl | grep 5559` prints nothing and logs give out errors!!!

4) Code above is running in debug mode: I can't seem to be able to step after the line `line = port_sniffer.stdout.readline()`

I tried using an iterator instead of a while loop (not that it should matter but still I am pointing it out). I also tried different values for bufsize (none, 1, and 8).

Please help!!

Comment: tcpflow is not a standard program.  Can you give background as to what `tcpflow -c -i any port 5559` does?  Does it only dump data to a file, or does it output information to stdout/stderr?

Comment: Oh, and FWIW http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: tcpflow captures tcp packets and writes their message body (without tcp overhead) to files or console. The -c flag makes it write its output to console.
I'd rather use shell=True because I don't know what other environment can run this program.

Comment: The problem was actually not in this code. The code I wrote works

Answer (score 2):

So after a quick read through [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) I found these two sentences:

> On Unix, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or
>   path of the program to execute

and

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
>   recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Based on this, I would recommend recreating your command as a list:

```
command = ["tcpflow -c", "-i any port 5559"]   #I don't know linux, so double check this line!!
```

The general idea is this (also from the docs):

> If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string,
>   and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to
>   the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
```

---

**Additionally**, it seems that to read from your process, you should use `communicate()`.  So

```
while True:
    line = port_sniffer.stdout.readline()
```

would become

```
while True:
    line = port_sniffer.communicate()[0]
```

But keep in mind this note from the docs:

> **Note** The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I don't think this solves the issue.
Using a list or a string does the same thing.

As for communicate, I haven't tried it because I know it is blocking. What I want to do is to read from stdout of tcpflow while it is running. I don't want for it to finish!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I think the problem that you're having is that you aren't running your program as root.  TCPFlow needs to be run as a privelaged user if you want to be able to sniff other people's traffic (otherwise that'd be a serious security vulnerability).  I wrote the following programs and they worked just fine for your scenario

server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
s = socket.socket()
host =  socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connection from', addr
    c.send('Test string 1234')
    c.recv(1024)
    while x != 'q':
        print "Received " + x
        c.send('Blah')
        x = c.recv(1024)
    print "Closing connection"
    c.close()
```

client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, sys
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.connect((host,port))
c = sys.stdin.read(1) # Type a char to send to initate the sending loop
while True:
   s.send(str(datetime.now()))
   s.sleep(3)
   msg = s.recv(1024)
```

flow.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
command = 'tcpflow -c -i any port 12345'
sniffer = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
while True:
   print sniffer.stdout.readline()
```